# Are Japan's neighbours opposed to a US apology for Hiroshima?

Tags: united-states, nuclear-weapons, japan, world-war-ii

In the discussion about the atomic bombing of Hiroshima and Nagasaki, I've heard about opinion within the United States, and opinion within Japan, such as the the Pew Research Center's article [70 years after Hiroshima, opinions have shifted on use of atomic bomb](http://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2015/08/04/70-years-after-hiroshima-opinions-have-shifted-on-use-of-atomic-bomb/). However, I haven't heard much about opinion in Japan's neighbours.

Doing a google news search came up with [The huge, strange coalition opposed to an Obama apology at Hiroshima](http://www.lowyinterpreter.org/post/2016/05/04/The-huge-strange-coalition-opposed-to-an-Obama-apology-at-Hiroshima.aspx) (via [The National Interest](http://nationalinterest.org/blog/the-buzz/the-huge-strange-coalition-opposed-obama-apology-hiroshima-16044?page=2))

> China and the Koreas
>
> Similarly, it takes little imagination to see how badly this would provoke China and the two Koreas. Memories of the Pacific War run deep, and resistance to Japan in that conflict are central legitimising narratives in all three countries.

I also came across a South Korean paper's op-ed column [U.S. president's first visit to Hiroshima seen through S. Korean eyes](http://U.S.%20president's%20first%20visit%20to%20Hiroshima%20seen%20through%20S.%20Korean%20eyes), which seems to oppose an apology without saying so outright:

> It would be unacceptable if the Abe government, which has distorted history of infliction without hesitation, takes advantage of Obama's visit to Hiroshima to dilute its responsibilities for the war and avoids facing its history of aggression.

However, I haven't found much in the way of hard evidence of whether or not Japan's neighbours are opposed to an apology.

Are some or all of Japan's neighbours (either the government or the population as a whole) opposed to a US apology for Hiroshima? By "Japan's neighbours", I mean those who were annexed, conquered or meaningfully invaded by Japan prior to or during WWII, and which has been a source of significant resentment.

Answer (score 3):

One reason might be the visits by senior political figures to the Yasukuni Shrine.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controversies_surrounding_Yasukuni_Shrine#Shinzo_Abe

The Japanese war on China many war crimes, for example the Rape of Nanking: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanking_Massacre

The Japanese Prisoner of War camps are notorious for their cruelty. Read James Clavell's best book (He did 3 years in one): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Rat_(Clavell_novel)

Japan has never apologised for this and many other war crimes which are well remembered by its neighbours. Successive prime ministers have visited the shrine to honour the perpetrators. Not good diplomacy but revealing about the level of denial in the Japanese electorate.

Japan's neighbours think Japan deserved what it got and that it, Japan, should apologise.